# How can I retrieve similar data from two separate tables simultaneously?

Tags: sql-server-2000

Disclaimer: my SQL skills are basic, to say the least.

Let's say I have two similar data types in different tables of the same database.

The first table is called **hardback** and the fields are as follows:

`hbID | hbTitle | hbPublisherID | hbPublishDate`

The second table is called **paperback** and its fields hold similar data but the fields are named differently:

`pbID | pbTitle | pbPublisherID | pbPublishDate`

I need to retrieve the 10 most recent hardback and paperback books, where the publisher ID is 7.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    hbID, hbTitle, hbPublisherID, hbPublishDate AS pDate
    bpID, pbTitle, bpPublisherID, pbPublishDate AS pDate
FROM hardback CROSS JOIN paperback
WHERE (hbPublisherID = 7) OR (pbPublisherID = 7)
ORDER BY pDate DESC
```

This returns seven columns per row, at least three of which may or may not be for the wrong publisher. Possibly four, depending on the contents of `pDate`, which is almost certainly going to be a problem if the other six columns are for the correct publisher!

In an effort to release an earlier version of this software, I ran two separate queries fetching 10 records each, then sorted them by date and discarded the bottom ten, but I just **know** there must be a more elegant way to do it!

Any suggestions?

*Aside: I was reviewing what I'd written here, when my Mac suddenly experienced a kernel panic. Restarted, reopened my tabs and everything I'd typed was still here! Stack Exchange sites are awesome :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably a `UNION`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
(SELECT hbID, hbTitle, hbPublisherID as PublisherID, hbPublishDate as pDate
 FROM hardback
 UNION 
 SELECT hpID, hpTitle, hpPublisher, hpPublishDate
 FROM paperback
) books
WHERE PublisherID = 7
```

If you could have two copies of the same title (1 paperback, 1 hardcover), change the `UNION` to a `UNION ALL`; `UNION` alone discards duplicates. You could also add a column that indicates what book type it is by adding a pseudo-column to each select (after the publish date, for instance):

```
hbPublishDate as pDate, 'H' as Covertype
```

You'll have to add the same new column to the paperback half of the query, using 'P' instead. Note that on the second query you don't have to specify column names; the resultset takes the names from the first one. All column data types in the two queries have match, also - you can't `UNION` a date column in the first with a numeric column in the second without converting the two columns to the same datatype in the query.

Here's a sample script for creating two tables and doing the select above. It works  just fine  in SQL Server Management Studio.Just remember to drop the two tables (using `DROP Table tablename`) when you're done.

```
use tempdb;
create table Paperback (pbID Integer Identity, 
    pbTitle nvarchar(30), pbPublisherID Integer, pbPubDate Date);
create table Hardback (hbID Integer Identity, 
    hbTitle nvarchar(30), hbPublisherID Integer, hbPubDate Date);

insert into Paperback (pbTitle, pbPublisherID, pbPubDate)
  values ('Test title 1', 1, GETDATE());
insert into Hardback (hbTitle, hbPublisherID, hbPubDate)
  values ('Test title 1', 1, GETDATE());

select * from (
  select pbID, pbTitle, pbPublisherID, pbPubDate, 'P' as Covertype
  from Paperback
  union all
  select hbID, hbTitle, hbPublisherID, hbPubDate,'H' 
  from Hardback) books
order by CoverType;

/* You'd drop the two tables here with
DROP table Paperback;
DROP table HardBack;
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I'm trying to get it to work, but getting syntax errors. I'm sure it's my fault, just didn't want you to think I was ignoring your answer, while I try to fix it...

Comment: What syntax errors are you getting? I don't see anything that would be questionable for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WERE'`. I'm going home for the weekend now, I'll try not to think about it until Monday morning :)

Comment: My fault. I forgot the alias on the inner select clause. Fixed.

Comment: That's probably because of the missing alias. See my edit, where I added the alias `books` before `WHERE`, and also my second code sample. :)

Comment: Adding the missing alias fixed it, that's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: May I politely request your attention on a follow-up question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/10170619/224684

Answer (score 0):

i think it is clearly better, if you make only one table with a reference to another one which holds information about the category of the entry like `hardback` or `paperback`. this is my first suggestion.

by the way, what is your programming language?

Comment: Yes, that would have been my first suggestion, too. Unfortunately, the second table was added some time after the first, for business-specific reasons (obviously it's not really two tables of books we're dealing with). I'm programming this in PHP.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the original question, because it doesn't answer the question asked. Suggesting a change to the database schema would be fine if you'd actually answer the question asked first. You forgot to do that, though. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) may be good to review, as it explains the difference between an answer and a comment; basically an answer *answers* the question asked (and then can contain other advice or information), while a comment just makes a suggestion as yours here does. :)

Comment: jup. later i realize that it was better to comment the question instead of write this as an answer. :)